# Axios - Different headers for Express Request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, axios

I start to develop an SSR React-Redux application, and i have a problem with axios headers.

**What is the proper way to set different header for each Express request?**

```js
Express.get('*', async (req, res) => {

  axios.defaults.headers.common = req.headers['my-customer-id'];

  // first axios get request
  // second axios get request
  // thirth axios get request

  //... initialization React App

});
```

With this approach, axios default headers are overwritten from last Express request.

I try to create different axios instance with `axios.create()`, but i don't know where and how to save the instance, for use inside application modules.

Answer (score 1):

there is a different between global headers and instance only headers:

```
// affects the global instance 
axios.defaults.headers.common['Auth-Token'] = 'foo bar';
```

```
//  affects to a single instance
axiosInstance.defaults.headers['Auth-Token'] = 'foo bar';
```

this works for me inside an expressjs app too, with different services (instances of axios)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new custom instance of axios using [create](https://github.com/axios/axios#creating-an-instance).

```
   const customAxios = axios.create({
      headers: {...req.headers['my-customer-id']}
    });
```

Now use customAxios to make the request

```
customAxios.get(...)
```